# Flutter error: OutlinedButton color: _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:693:3)

Tags: flutter

I am getting the below error which happens sporadically. Which is linked to the material widgets: OutlinedButton and also SwitchListTile.

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following StackOverflowError was thrown building OutlinedButton(style: ButtonStyle#dc6a2(foregroundColor: _OutlinedButtonDefaultColor#e3bc0, overlayColor: _OutlinedButtonDefaultOverlay#5f70a, side: MaterialStatePropertyAll(BorderSide(width: 0.0, style: none))), dependencies: [MediaQuery, _InheritedTheme, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#28c3a]], state: _ButtonStyleState#ac5c5):
Stack Overflow

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  OutlinedButton OutlinedButton:file:///Users/mac/Documents/flutter_projects/zense_timer_project/zense_timer/lib/pages/home_page/banner_settings/custom_home_button.dart:35:20
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:693:3)
#1      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#2      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#3      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#4      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#5      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#6      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#7      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#8      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#9      _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#10     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#11     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#12     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#13     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#14     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#15     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#16     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#17     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#18     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#19     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#20     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#21     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#22     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#23     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#24     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#25     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#26     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#27     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#28     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#29     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#30     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#31     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#32     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#33     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#34     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#35     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#36     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#37     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#38     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#39     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#40     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#41     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#42     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
#43     _LerpProperties.resolve (package:flutter/src/material/material_state.dart:695:29)
...
...
#4232   RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#4233   RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#4234   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4235   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4236   RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#4237   RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#4238   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4239   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4240   MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:171:12)
#4241   _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:1056:7)
#4242   MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:235:7)
#4243   RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:403:14)
#4244   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4245   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4246   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#4247   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4248   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4249   RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:122:14)
#4250   _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1449:11)
#4251   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4252   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4253   RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#4254   RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#4255   RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2395:7)
#4256   RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2386:11)
#4257   RenderStack._computeSize (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:580:43)
#4258   RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:607:12)
#4259   RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2234:7)
#4260   PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1016:18)
#4261   RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:492:19)
#4262   WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:905:13)
#4263   RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:358:5)
#4264   SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1284:15)
#4265   SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1214:9)
#4266   SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1072:5)
#4267   _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
#4268   PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:359:5)
#4269   _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
====================================================================================================
```

> **Note:** I only noticed this error on an iPhone simulator not when using an AVD so far.

Code for where the custom buttons are housed (children of a Row widet).

```
return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: SizedBox(
        height: kToolbarHeight * 1.25,
        width: size.width,
        child: appState.sessionState == SessionState.notStarted ?
          IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: appState.sessionState != SessionState.notStarted,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: backgroundColor,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(kBorderRadiusBig),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(kBorderRadiusBig),
                ),
              ),

              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  CustomHomeButton(
                    title: bellTitle,
                    iconData: !audioState.bellOnStart &&
                            audioState.bellSound.name == kNone &&
                            audioState.bellOnEndSound.name == kNone
                        ? FontAwesomeIcons.bellSlash
                        : FontAwesomeIcons.bell,
                    onPressed: () {
                      /// callback code...
                    },
                  ),
                  CustomHomeButton(
                    title: audioState.ambience.toText(),
                    iconData: audioState.ambience.toIcon(),
                    onPressed: () async {
                           /// callback code...
                    },
                  ),
                  CustomHomeButton(
                      title: appState.selectedPreset == ""
                          ? kPresets
                          : appState.selectedPreset,
                      iconData: Icons.tune_outlined,
                      onPressed: () {
                           /// callback code...
                      }),
                  //// etc....
```

And custom button widget code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_animate/flutter_animate.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:zense_timer/configs/constants.dart';
import 'package:zense_timer/state/app_state.dart';

class CustomHomeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomHomeButton({
    super.key,
    required this.iconData,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.title,
  });

  final String? title;
  final IconData iconData;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return SizedBox(
          width: size.width / 4,
          height: size.height * 0.8,
          child: OutlinedButton(
            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                side: BorderSide.none,
            ),


/// ERROR occuring here...

            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: size.height * 0.003),
                  child: Center(child: Icon(iconData)),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: size.width / 4,
                  height: size.height * 0.018,
                  child: title != null
                      ? Text(
                          title!,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .labelSmall!
                              .copyWith(
                                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
                                  fontSize: 8,),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        )
                      : null,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );

  }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine for me. Could you please share more detail like the `child:` widget of `OutlinedButton`.

Comment: I added more code, the custom widget I created (full code) and also snippet of parent widget housed in a row widget. Thank you,